# Construct a $\sigma$-algebra $A$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Construct a $\sigma$-algebra $A$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that no open interval is measurable with respect to $A$, although any singleton $\{x\}$ is ($x \in \mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1):

You will want all $\{ x \}$ to be in $A$, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then all countable sets have to be in $A$. And their complements.

This suggests taking
$$
A = \{ S \subseteq \mathbb{R} : \text{$S$ or $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ is countable} \}.
$$

Now please verify that this is a $\sigma$-algebra, and that it contains no open interval besides $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: do you mean that any interval in R has uncountable complement, but how we can approve it.

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncontable?

Comment: yes i know that but it ok to say that since R is uncountable therefore no open interval is countable or has countable complement.

Comment: Do you know that there is a bijection between any open interval and $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: let B in A that means B in R, suppose that B is countable so, R\B is uncountable, and since R is uncountable which is covered R\B , then B complement ⊆ R , and B complement in A. Is this correct way to approve sigma algebra?